# Does lower power affect a MacBook Pro negatively?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, dock, power, apple-silicon

I've got a new MacBook Pro 16" 2021 with a Pro M1 processor. It is specced to use a 140W MagSafe power adapter.

I already have a USB-C dock (a [Belkin Thunderpolt 3](https://www.belkin.com/us/business/hubs-and-docks-for-business/docking-stations-for-business/thunderbolt-3-express-dock-hd-dual-4k-display-85w-psu/p/p-f4u095/)) through which I have connected two external monitors, ethernet, and other USB devices. The dock also delivers up to 85W power. It is very convenient since I only need to connect a single USB-c to the MacBook to get all external data connections.

The dock delivers "only" 85W but, for convenience, I would like to connect **just** the USB-c cable to the dock, and not have to also connect the 140W USB-C power adapter. Would acting that way have any negative consequences?

Putting it another way: The maximum power that can be fed to the MacBook is 140W. Does that mean that during some usages of the MacBook it actually *needs* 140W to function optimally?

If it needs more than 85W, will it "take" some power from the battery? From my usage so far, the battery is constantly full, and the MacBook has been working well.

I do have some heavy usages scenarios: I do compilations of large amounts of code. Will the performance of those potentially be worse if the MacBook is only connected to 85W?

Answer (score 1):

I like the "bath" analogy for this. Your laptop's battery is a bath, full of water.

Using the laptop is like pulling the plug: the rate at which water leaves the bath depends on how much work you're doing.

Charging the laptop is like turning the taps on.

If the taps can supply more water than is leaving via the plug, then the bath will fill. If they supply less than is leaving the bath, then the bath will drain.

The 140W rating has to cover maximum power usage, so 100% CPU, 100% GPU, charging the battery, powering peripherals, screen on full brightness, etc, etc. So for most uses, the power draw should be significantly below that.

Comment: Only difference: You have a magical bath that closes the taps instead of overflowing the bath. And closes the plug a bit before the bath is completely empty so you don’t run out of water.

Answer (score 0):

The MacBook will take power from the battery if it can’t get enough from the charger for the current load.

If the battery needs charging then it will charge at whatever rate possible that is left after supplying the load. So, it will likely be slower or, if you have a large load, the battery may not charge at all and discharge.

Comment: As far as I can see my battery is constantly at 100%. So, does that then mean that the current power (85W) is enough and performance is unaffected?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn: In the *historical aggregate*, yes. But this may not always be true - your macbook's power consumption is affected by many things; just because you've not used more than 85W *so far* does not mean that you never will.

Comment: The new MBP do not throttle their power on battery at all. This has been tested by some YouTubers like LinusTechTips or MaxTech. Therefore I doubt you will ever notice any difference, the only problem you will run into is, if you constantly use all the resources it will draw 140W and at some point the battery will die. However, maxing out the new MBP needs the CPU and GPU slammed to their maximum and compiling code will most likely not use much GPU.

Comment: @X_841: when you write *the battery will die* do you mean that it will enter a state from which it needs to be revived by the provision of more electrons, or that it will enter a state from which it cannot be revived?  Will the battery have gone to join the choir eternal or will it be merely resting on its perch?

Comment: Oh no sorry, this was confusing. I meant the battery will be completely discharged, therefore you need to recharge it and you will be able to use it again. However, Lithium-Ion batteries don't "like" being completely discharged, i.e. while it does not kill the battery it does hurt it a little. So always going down to 0% battery is not a good idea, yet its not a problem if it happens occasionally. Heat will have a more severe impact on the batteries longevity.

Comment: On an Intel MBP with 45 Watt charger instead of the correct 85 Watt, and all four cores working hard, the effect was that the battery emptied, but at a few percent, the MBP reduced its clock rate to 1 GHz. Now it used less than 45 Watt, so the battery filled slowly, and when it reached maybe 15% it switched back to full speed, emptied the battery down to a few percent, and repeat forever. I expect a Silicon MacBook to do about the same. Apple will be clever enough to not allow you to damage the MacBook or the battery.

Answer (score 0):

The 140 Watt are mostly used for charging your MacBook quickly. It will be very rare that your MacBook uses more than 85 Watt, and even more rare that it uses more continuously. Maybe if you plug in an iPhone and an iPad and charge them from the MacBook.

*If* you use 140 Watts then your MacBook will work just fine, but its battery will discharge slowly. Since you are 55 Watt short, every minute where you don’t use the Mac will give you 1 1/2 minutes of additional charge. Turning down brightness, turning off WiFi if not used, will get you more time. And of course you can use 100 Watt all day and still have charge left because you only discharge by 15 Watt.